# Prove that $n \ln(n) - n \le \ln(n!)$ without Stirling

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I need to prove that  $n \ln(n) - n \le \ln(n!)$. I have solved this but I've used the Stirling substitution for the factorial term which does not seem good to me in this proof. I am sure that there must be a direct way to solve this. 
One way I can think about tackling this problem is simply breaking the left and right hand side into primary terms: 
$$\ln(n!) = \ln(n) + \ln(n-1) + \ln(n-2) + \dots + \ln(2) + \ln(1)$$
$$n \ln(n) - n = n (\ln(n)-1) = (\ln(n) - 1) + (\ln(n) -1) + \dots + (\ln(n) -1)$$
 
I need to somehow show that the the top expression is greater than the bottom expression, but I can only be sure that $\ln(n) > \ln(n) -1$ and that $ \ln(n-1)>\ln(n) - 1$ 
What can I do about the rest?

Comment: $\ln(n)-n$ is negative! Do you mean $n-\ln(n)$?

Comment: @OmG, I meant $n ln(n) - n$. Thank you for correction.

Comment: @BarryCipra  I have corrected that in text, Too. Thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$ n \log n - n +1 = \int_1^n \; \; \log x \; \; dx < \sum_{j = 2}^n \log j \; = \log n!  $$

diagram for $n=4$

[image]

Comment: Actually $n \log n - n \color{red}{+1}  = \int_1^n \; \; \log x \; \; dx$, giving a slightly sharper result.

Answer (score 12):

Recall that the sequence 
$$ e_n = \left( 1+ \frac 1n \right)^n $$
is increasing and converges to $e$. Thus, 
$$ e^n \ge e_1 \cdot e_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot e_n = \frac{(n+1)^n}{n!}. $$
In particular we obtain the weaker inequality $e^n \ge \frac{n^n}{n!}$, which is equivalent to $n \ln n - n \le \ln (n!)$.

---

A by-product of this is that the sequence 
$$ \sqrt[n]{e_1 \cdot e_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot e_n} = \frac{n+1}{\sqrt[n]{n!}} $$
is increasing and tends to $e$ (by an application of [Stolz-Cesaro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)).

Comment: very nice, I used a similar idea by induction but this is more elegant!

Answer (score 9):

As an alternative note that

$$ n \ln n - n \le \ln(n!)\iff e^{n \ln n - n}\le e^{\ln(n!)}\iff \frac{n^n}{e^n}\le n!$$

which can be proved by induction as follow

**base case**

- $n=1 \implies  \frac1e \le 1$

**induction step**

- assume $\frac{n^n}{e^n}\le n!$
- $\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{e^{n+1}}=\frac{n+1}{e}\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n}\frac{n^n}{e^n}\le \frac{n+1}{e}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n n!\le(n+1)n!=(n+1)!$