# Is $\ln(x!)/x$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Hello I have a question:

Is $limx→∞log(x!) / x$ convergent?

It seems like it gets stuck around $3$. But I am not so sure about this function. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Is $x \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: yes it is......

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "it gets stuck around $3$".  Anyway, look at Stirling's approximation.

Comment: Hello and welcome. You are asking whether the average of the numbers $\ln 1, \ln 2, \dots, \ln x$ remains bounded as $x$ becomes large. But $\ln x \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$. So ...?

Comment: when I check it for 100000000000 it is around 3

Comment: But $\log(x!)$ is growing faster than $x$, even though it is slow.

Comment: @bebe I suspect there's an error in your calculation, then.

Comment: @HansEngler Yes but I thought n was getting bigger faster than the sum of lnx (for x values starting from 1.) You think I was wrong?

Comment: For $x=10^4$ your expression is $8.21089$.

Comment: @bebe - Numerical approximations can be deceiving.  Pick any $k$ as large as you want and consider $x = e^{k+5}$, for example. Then more than 99% of the numbers between 1 and $x$ are larger than $e^k$. Each of these contributes at least $k$ to $\ln x!$. Now estimate the fraction.

Comment: @bebe I suggest that you clarify the OP.  Certainly $\frac{\log(x!)}{x}$ is continuous for all real values of $x$ with $x>0$.  As such, $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\log(x!)}{x}=\frac{\log(a!)}{a}$ converges. Are you trying to evaluate the limit as $a\to 0$?  Are you trying to evaluate the limit as $a\to \infty$?

Comment: @MarkViola a→∞.

Comment: @bebe Please modify your OP to state that you're seeking $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\log(x!)}{x}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stirling's approximation states $\ln x!\approx \ln \sqrt{2\pi}+(x+\frac{1}{2})\ln x-x$, so $\frac{\ln x!}{x}\sim\ln x$. This diverges as $x\to\infty$, albeit slowly enough you might not have noticed it with numerical experiments. Judging by your conjecture that the function converges to a value approximating $3$, I'm guessing you tried values of $x$ up to approximately $\exp 3\approx 20$.

Answer (score 2):

As shown here

- [Prove that $n \ln(n) - n \le \ln(n!)$ without Stirling](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2681474/505767)

we have that

$$ \ln(n!)\ge n \ln n - n$$

then

$$\frac{\ln n!}{n}\ge \ln n -1$$

Answer (score 2):

No, the sequence does not converge.

We have $$ \frac {\ln (n!)}{n} = \frac {1}{n} \sum_1^n \ln k$$

That is a Riemann's sum for the integral $$\int _0^1 \ln(nx)dx = \ln(n) -1$$Which diverges to $\infty$