# Determine $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{ (n!)!^\frac{1}{n!} } $

Tags: real-analysis

I am able to establish that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{ n! ^\frac{1}{n} } $ converges to 0.

I suspect that $\frac{1}{ (n!)!^\frac{1}{n!} } $ is a subsequence of $ \frac{1}{ n! ^\frac{1}{n} } $ which would make the problem much easier to deal with. Is this a valid approach to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: write down$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{ (n!)!^\frac{1}{n!} }{=\lim_{m\to \infty}\frac{1}{ (m)!^\frac{1}{m} } } $$and apply Stirling's approx. for $m!$.

Comment: Think I got it. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question...

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\frac{1}{ (n!)!^\frac{1}{n!} }=e^{\frac{\log (n!)!}{n!}}$$

and then by $m=n!$ and by [$m!\ge \frac{m^m}{e^m}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2681514/505767)

$$\frac{\log (n!)!}{n!}=\frac{\log m!}{m}\ge \log \frac{m}{e}$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a valid approach to the question, because $(n!)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a subsequence of $(n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$. And if a sequence converges, then all of its subsequences converge too.