# Computing $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n!}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I am trying to compute the expression

$$\limsup_{n\to \infty}|n!|^\frac{1}{n}$$

My thinking is that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}|n!^\frac{1}{n}|=\lim_{n\to \infty}n!^\frac{1}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^\frac{\log n!}{n} = e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n!}{n}}$$

Then I must compute $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n!}{n}$.

From here, I am not sure where to go. How can I compute this limit?

Comment: $\log(n!)=\log(2)+\log(3)+\cdots+\log(n-1)+\log(n)$

Comment: [Here is a post about $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\log(n!)}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3030037/show-that-lim-n-to-infty-frac-lnnn-infty)

Comment: Using pxel comment: $\frac{log(n!)}{n}\gt \frac{log(n/2)}{2}\to \infty$