# Prove that $\forall n \in N: \ln(n!) \geq n\ln(n)-n+1$

Tags: calculus

I thought about Stirling equation for the solution but I couldn't get the answer.

How i need to approach in order to solve that?

Comment: What about Induction ?

Comment: Closely related: [Prove that $n \ln(n) - n ≤ \ln(n!)$ without Stirling](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2681474/prove-that-n-lnn-n-le-lnn-without-stirling).

Comment: @TobyMak: Actually the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2681484/42969) to that question gives this result, because (unless I am mistaken) $n \log n - n + 1 = \int_1^n \; \; \log x \; \; dx$

Comment: This is clearly a duplicate of another question on this site. Thanks for finding it Martin.

Comment: @TobyMak: Easy with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%20%5Cln(n!)%20%5Cgeq%20n%5Cln(n)-n%2B1%24&p=1) !